# How can I specify queue size used by jquery animate() function

Tags: jquery, animation

The [documents](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on jquery site tell me I can use "queue" option to put animations in the effects queue when invoking the `animate()` fuction. What will happen if there is so many animations that memory is not enough? How can I specify size of the queue to drop the animations that overflow?

Answer (score 0):

This type of  situation handled by [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) with [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). As per it's document:

> Promise: Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a certain type
> bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.
>
> Done: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.

```
.animate('Your-Selectot')
.promise()
.done(function () {
    $(this).css('backgroud-color', 'blue'); // Its only sample to describe situation. 
});
```

`done` callback is called after collection emptied their queues.